# How to move letter from each string to a new string using struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, class, struct

I need to create a struct that move each latter from the two string and take it to a new string. Example string "world"
                         string "book"
                 output "wboorolkd"
I build the struct but I couldn't get to the output here what I did

I am new to C#

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myprogram_Struct
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(person1.name);
        person1.SetName("david");
        Console.WriteLine(person1.name);
        Person person2 = new Person("sarah");
        Console.WriteLine(person2.name);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    }
}
public struct Person
{

    public string name;
    public Person(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }

    public void SetName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You code does not have any logic for achieving the feature you mentioned above. You need try to write that logic first and come back here if  you face any problem in that. The logic is to zip the two string character by character and create a new string out of them. Hint : string is a collection of characters..

Comment: What should be the behaviour if one string is longer than the other?

Comment: The solutions given so far are limited to two strings, is that what you want - or did you want a solution for x number of strings to be combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no sure if that is what you want, but if I understood you right, you can do it like this:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string name1;
    public string name2;

    public string merge()
    {
        string retval = "";

        int length = name1.Length;

        if (length < name2.Length)
            length = name2.Length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (name1.Length > i)
                retval += name1[i];

            if (name2.Length > i)
                retval += name2[i];
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work but your program is close to what .answer my rotem was correct but he didn't use struct as the homework asked . Thank you

Comment: I copied it and It worked fine. What is the error? I would say Rotem and my answer is nearly the same. Ofcours you can also take Rotems answer and put it into a struct.

Answer (score 3):

A wordier and more naive solution than @Rango's answer, but may be clearer for a beginner.

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "defxyz";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int max = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    if (i < a.Length)
    {
        sb.Append(a[i]);
    }
    if (i < b.Length)
    {
        sb.Append(b[i]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I think your Math.Max solution is better than my solution. Didn't thought about that. But why do you use a StringBuilder, ist there a performance difference between StringBuilder.Append() and String += Char ?

Comment: @Ahrtaler Yes, it is more efficient, but it's negligible with such short strings.

Comment: I like this solution more than mine. If you're not so familiar with LINQ you will understand this easier and it's also efficient even with large strings.

Comment: @Rango Most efficient would be to combine the loop with your `remainder` bit.

Comment: Rotem, thank you so much for the code, it works as I wanted but the professor wanted to be used as struct and that what killing me as I know how to do it ,it just I can't get struct in my head and I wish you can help me with that

Comment: @F.David it's hard to understand what you mean by that. A struct is a data structure, your question is about an algorithm.

Comment: This is what the assiggnment was about and I figure out how to solve it Thank you so much

Comment: @F.David I can only recommend finding a better instructor.

Comment: I was about to drop the class, but I missed the deadline. He asked usless assignment and teach nothing and basicly I am teaching myself